# Server Side Render re-render at client

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, server-side-rendering

I trying to implement server side render with django, express, react and react-router-dom.

server.js

```
const html = renderToString((
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StaticRouter basename={baseUrl} location={location} context={context}>
        <AppRoute />
      </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
  ), null, 2);

  const preloadedState = store.getState();

  res.send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState))
```

index.js for client.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <AppRoute />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

AppRoute uses RouteAsync for client and RouteSync for server

AppRoute.js import

```
import {App} from './RouteSync'
import {CollegeList} from './RouteSync'
import {CollegeDetail} from './RouteSync'
```

RouteAsync.js

```
export const App = asyncRoute(() => System.import('../app'));
export const CollegeList = asyncRoute(() => System.import('../apps/college/CollegeList'));
export const CollegeDetail = asyncRoute(() => System.import('../apps/college/CollegeDetail'));
```

RouteSync.js

```
export { default as App } from '../app'
export { default as CollegeList } from '../apps/college/CollegeList'
export { default as CollegeDetail } from '../apps/college/CollegeDetail'
```

webpack NormalModuleReplacementPlugin changes RouteSync to RouteAsync

```
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      /\.\/RouteSync$/,
      './RouteAsync'
    ),
```

Server render is done and send to client. At client after SSR client again re-render the whole page when viewed from devtools performance.

[devtools "performance" image showing blank page before client re-render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LS3P.png)

I hope react would only hook event listeners, not render the page.

Any suggestion to stop re-render in client side.

Comment: did you happen to find a solution? I am running into this in our production app after updating to react-router 4 (react-router-dom)

Comment: Component those are import form asyncRoute are re-render but component that are loaded from Sync method are not re-render.

For solution: 
1. I choose the component which must not be re-render. 
2. In RouteAsync.js file those component are imported as in RouteSync.js 

So, selected component are not re-rendered at client.
This was only solution I came up after I reading

Comment: "Code-splitting + server rendering" topic in https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/code-splitting

Answer (score 1):

I also did not find answer for this. And created my own starter. It uses react-router v4, redux, redux-saga. To prevent re-render on the client for the first link open there used hydrate method. I’ve created this based of official docs and suggestions from react-router v4 and redux. Hope it helps.

https://github.com/gzoreslav/react-redux-saga-universal-application